Brightness slider not appearing, can't adjust brightness with F keys (Razer Blade 15, early 2021 with Noveau drivers)
Ever since having to switch to Noveau drivers after a recent RAM upgrade (ALL of the proprietary ones now hang near the end of installation for a very long time and then invariably puke), even after adding "acpi_backlight=vendor" to grub I still can't even get the brightness slider to show up, and it seems to be stuck on maximum brightness. (If it helps, I am using X11 as my display server; when the stars still aligned with driver 550, the backlight adjustment slider was working fine.) Any help would be much appreciated.
UPDATE: Disregard this, I have now gotten the stars to re-align regarding the official driver; all I had to do was disable SecureBoot in the BIOS after reinstalling the driver using console mode, then get rid of the NVIDIA wake and sleep daemons and add the "lid default state" param to grub to re-fix the suspend bugs.
